# 2000 Worker Threads and only few real

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio

I paused VS and came to the thread window. I see there > 2000 "Worker Thread" entries with the same call stack and different Id's (threads are created with `Task.Factory.StartNew`
method).

All these threads are waiting for one lock to be unlocked. This can be a bug in my application. The issue, that when I come to the task manager, i see +- standard amount of thread and memory usage. Is this a CLR optimization to not have many idle thread, or VS thread window bug?

Comment: [Thread != Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#How_threads_differ_from_processes)

Comment: @Corak Did OP compared thread with a process?

Comment: Could be a bug, i had something similar, some code i thought would start a new thread everytime a call came in (and paused while waiting for one) did in fact create threads all the time. And didnt wait for the call to happen. Every call to StartNew will create a new thread. If this doesnt solve it, could you maybe post some of the code? (See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Task != Thread. In fact Tasks have been added just to have a lightweight solution for multi-tasking. Read the basics on msdn about Tasks.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - No. Sorry, the mention of Task Manager made me jump to conclusions.

Comment: @GameAlchemist `Task != Thread` I agree, but what you see in `Threads window` of visual studio are really threads. That's what OP is taking about. (May be a bug though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in your code.  Deadlock is one of the universal threading bugs.

Getting to 2000 threads is possible.  It is the job of the ThreadPool manager to limit the number of threads that can run.  Governed by its SetMaxThreads() method.  The default is a ridiculously large number, 1023 on my 4 core laptop.  Depends on the .NET version as well, you probably have an 8 core machine.  Actually getting that many started takes a while.

Deadlock is the easier threading bug to solve, you've got a *lot* of time to look at the call stacks to figure out where they are deadlocking.  Unlike threading race bugs, the really nasty ones you're liable to get when you remove whatever lock causes the deadlock right now.  Temporarily calling ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 10000) to limit the carnage is a decent strategy to not drown in the number of threads to look at and make the debugging attempt seem futile.

Comment: Question was slightly different, about why that why count of threads in taskmanager can be much smaller that in VS thread windows. But i like your answer, it is good idea with ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads. So thanks, i accept it.

Comment: uh.. i got some extra pain(new dead-lock) when set  ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 10000) ... when i set this up, some methods which should initialize my service failed to start for ever because i need more than 4 task at the same time. So we need be very carefully when limiting this value

Comment: Congratulations, you've figured out how to diagnose what goes wrong with your program in *seconds* rather than hours.  This *will* go wrong as well in production, much much harder to diagnose.